# Cant find symbol on outputStr

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestScores
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     { 
        double testscore1, testscore2, testscore3, testscore4;
        double weigh1, weigh2, weigh3, weigh4;

        String testscore1Str, testscore2Str, testscore3Str, testscore4Str;

        testscore1Str = 
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first score: ");
        testscore1 = Double.parseDouble(testscore1Str);

        testscore2Str = 
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second score: ");
        testscore2 = Double.parseDouble(testscore2Str);

        testscore3Str = 
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third score: ");
        testscore3 = Double.parseDouble(testscore3Str);

        testscore4Str = 
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter fourth score: ");
        testscore4 = Double.parseDouble(testscore4Str);

        weigh1 = testscore1 * 0.20;
        weigh2 = testscore2 * 0.35;
        weigh3 = testscore2 * 0.15;
        weigh4 = testscore2 * 0.30;

        outputStr = "testscore1: " + weigh1 + "/n" +
                    "testscore2: " + weigh2 + "/n" +
                    "testscore3: " + weigh3 + "/n" +
                    "testscore4: " + weigh4 + "/n";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr, "TestScores",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
        }

}
```

I'm having a can't find symbol error on the "outputStr".

Usually it's just a simple misspelling, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any pointers to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You never declare `outputStr`, so what did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
outputStr = "testscore1: " + weigh1 + "/n" +
            "testscore2: " + weigh2 + "/n" +
            "testscore3: " + weigh3 + "/n" +
            "testscore4: " + weigh4 + "/n";
```

You fail to initialize `outputStr`. Try this:

```
String outputStr = "testscore1: " + weigh1 + "/n" +
            "testscore2: " + weigh2 + "/n" +
            "testscore3: " + weigh3 + "/n" +
            "testscore4: " + weigh4 + "/n";
```

In the future, please try to do some basic debugging before asking on Stack Overflow. Check out [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. Also, writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) really helps to identify bugs.

An IDE will also explicitly point out errors like this as you make them. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) and [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) are two good Java IDE's.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I missed such a simple thing